# Substract Select(Sum) Group By of two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables, stock_in and stock_out. To find out stock levels, I need to subtract stock_out from stock_in. I'm not sure where to start and I've tried the below query which didn't work. I've created tables below to show what I'm looking to achieve.

```
SELECT (SELECT item, size, SUM(qty) AS qty FROM stock_in GROUP BY item, size) - (SELECT item, size, SUM(qty) AS qty FROM stock_out GROUP BY item, size)
```

```
stock_in table
|item   | size | qty |
|:------|:----:|----:|
|PhoneX | XL   |  2  |
|PhoneY | L    |  3  |
|PhoneZ | XL   |  2  | 
|PhoneX | XL   |  2  |

stock_out table
|item   | size | qty |
|:------|:----:|----:|
|PhoneX | XL   |  1  |
|PhoneY | L    |  2  |
|PhoneZ | XL   |  1  | 
|PhoneX | XL   |  2  |

result (avaliable stock)
|item   | size | qty |
|:------|:----:|----:|
|PhoneX | XL   |  1  |
|PhoneY | L    |  1  |
|PhoneZ | XL   |  1  |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is just not going to work because the subqueries can return multiple rows -- and that is not permitted for *scalar subqueries*.

I would suggest `union all` and aggregation:

```
select item, size, sum(qty)
from ((select item, size, qty
       from stock_in
      ) union all
      (select item, size, - qty
       from stock_out
      )
     ) sio
group by item, size;
```